# XAML designer intellisense-like structured suggestion

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

With given class (containing hundreds of constants)

```
public class Objects
{
    public class Cars
    {
        public class Opel
        {
            public const string Corsa = "Some parameters";
            ...
        }
        public class Ford { ... }
        ...
    }
}
```

it is very easy to find needed constant in code behind (talking about intellisense suggestions):

```
var parameter = Objects.Cars.Opel.Corsa;
```

When typing `Objects.` you will be prompted with `Cars`, after typing `Objects.Cars.` there will be a suggestion with `Opel`, `Ford`, etc. and finally after `Object.Cars.Opel` there will be a suggestion with `Corsa` (among others).

My question is what approach should I use to provide same kind of suggestion in xaml designer?

---

To example, if I have markup extension and I'd like to assist programmer in choosing proper value out of a list, then I could make `enum`, set property of that type and rest happens auto-magically:

[image]

However, when dealing with hundreds of constants I'd prefer to have some kind of structured selection, similar to described earlier intellisense support with nested classes suggestion.

And I am struggling to find a *nice* way of how to organize that. Any ideas?